# Why not both standardize and normalize features for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, lstm, standardization

If one has data that's assumed to be normal distributed and want to use it as input in a machine learning model, why not first standardize the data and then normalize (min max scale it between zero and one)?

So first transform as follows

$$
S = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}
$$

...and then transform it one more time to
$$
X_{standaardizedAndNormalized} = \frac{S - S_{min}}{S_{max}-S_{min}}
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is equivalent to normalizing only $X$ since the standardization step does not change the min/max values. Besides, these transformations are not associated with normality assumption.

Comment: Indeed, an assumption of normality of inputs is rarely a requirement

Comment: If you did the transforms in the opposite order "normalize" then "standardize" you would get the same as just "standardize".  Both are location-scale transformations.

Comment: What's the downside of first standardizing and then normalizing? If there isn't any downside, why not just always do that?

Comment: The first operation is a waste of resources